# Seeking papers on multi-factor models on the equity long short hedge funds

Tags: equities, regression, hedge-fund

I am seeking papers that use regression  & multi-factor models for equity long-short funds.

I am interested in understanding the funds' behavior and exposure to various factors using some quantitative techniques such as regression.

For example, I ran regression of financials equity long/short funds against various sectors and the financials sector was not statistically significant while Information Technology was!

These are some mysteries I want to understand.

**Thank you very much in your help.**